# Test for overflow in integer addition

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to detect integer overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

i have tried to implement simple program which tests if overflow occurs during integer addition:

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string overflow(long a,long b){
    return ((a+b)>UINT_MAX)?"true":"false";
}

int main(){
    long a, b;
    cout << "enter a and b: ";
    cin >> a >> b;
    string m = overflow(a,b);
    cout << m;

    return 0;
}
```

`UINT_MAX=65535`  so  i have entered  65535  and 20 but it wrote false why?

Comment: How about a > (UINT_MAX - b), You can't assume that long is larger than int (it may be the same size)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given `unsigned int a, b`, this expression can never evaluate to `true`:

```
(a+b) > UINT_MAX
```

The reason why it can't ever be `true` is because `UINT_MAX` is the max, so whatever result `(a+b)` is can never be greater than `UINT_MAX`, because that would be a contradiction.

You tried to use a bigger data type `long` to get around this, but this is actually not guaranteed to be bigger than `int` in C++. You may want to try `long long` instead (although this type does not exist in standard C++).

Unlike, say, Java, C++ does not actually specify how large each data type must be, so the claim that `UINT_MAX=65535` is not universally true. It's only true for processors where an unsigned integer is held in 16 bits. For 32 bits, `UINT_MAX` is `4294967295`.

#### Related questions

- [Best way to detect integer overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Limits.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h)
- [cplusplus.com/reference/library/climits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/)

Comment: Also, he's using signed integers (or, at least, not specifically asking for unsigned ones) meaning that the maximum value is half of `UINT_MAX`

Comment: you are right maximum value of UINT_MAX  is not 65535   i have seen this in cplusplus.com in my computer   maximum value is what you wrote thanks

Comment: @davit: from cplusplus.com "Any particular compiler implementation may define integral types with greater magnitudes than those shown here" ; C++ leaves many things up to implementation

Answer (score 3):

```
unsigned int a = UINT_MAX;
unsigned int b = 20;

unsigned int c = a+b;

cout << c << endl;

//output
19
```

There is already some questions on SO about overflow detection (e.g. [Best way to detect integer overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c) ). May be you'll find them helpful

Answer (score 2):

What compiler are you using?

On most systems an integer is a 32bit signed type, which gives +/- 2.1 billion (give or take a couple).

65535 is a 16bit value so adding 20 to it wouldn't do much, but I am surprised that it gives false.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems:

65535 is 2^16 or 2 bytes where as a long is generally 4 bytes long or 2^32. You could change your program to use shorts which are generally 2 bytes long

Some compilers now provide 2^64 for longs (a long must be at least 2^32 but can be larger). Similar rules apply to shorts.

You are using signed long which means one bit is used to denote a sign so even if you were using shorts entering 65535 would actually be a value of -1 (so change to use unsigned shorts)

if you add two unsigned shorts together and put the answer into a short the total can never be more than 65535 because a short can't denote that large a value.

Answer (score 1):

Two things

1. check size of long - if it is same as int, this will (a+b) will always be smaller than or equal to UINT_MAX
2. UINT_MAX = 4294967295 for a 4 bit integer

It is all platform dependent

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string overflow(unsigned int a,unsigned int b)
{ 
    return ((a > (std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() - b))?"true":"false"; 
}
```

Remember there is no gurantee that long is bigger than int so any code that assumes the long will store a larger number is flawed. So we can not do the sum to see if it overflows because by the time it overflows it is too late. So rearrange the symbols so the part of the expression is on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return ((a+b)>(long)UINT_MAX)?"true":"false";
```

Also, make sure UINT_MAX really is 65535 and not something larger.

Comment: That's still not going to work a+b has overflowed before it is converted to long.