# The expression of detection with the unsigned integer overflow

Tags: c

The program will generate factorial number until it occurs overflow. The expression `r <= UINT_MAX / j` is to detect the overflow. For now, if I rewrite the expression to this `r * j <= UINT_MAX`, it will enter the infinite loop. My question is NOT about how to detect the integer overflow. That is why the expression will let the process enter the infinite loop.

```
for (unsigned i = 0;;++i) {
    unsigned r = 1;
    for (unsigned j = 2; j <= i; ++j) {
        if (r <= UINT_MAX / j) 
            r *= j;
        else {
            printf("Overflow!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The expression `r * j` is also an unsigned int. So it can never be larger than `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test for overflow in integer addition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422709/test-for-overflow-in-integer-addition)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect integer overflow in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsigned integer types have arithmetic **modulo** its maximum value plus 1.
In your case, we have arithmetic modulo `(UINT_MAX+1)`.

So, the operation `r*j` always gives a result `<= UINT_MAX`, and the comparison is always true.

However, when `r`  is compared against `UINT_MAX / j`, the **real** (mathematical) arithmetic coincides with the unsigned type arithmetic, because `UINT_MAX / j` is mathematically in the range of `unsigned`.
This explains why in the C-code the condition would be true or false exactly the same way as the mathematical comparison is.

Thus, the `r <= UINT_MAX/j` approach is the correct one.